# Dashboard/tunnel error - Magento

Tags: php, magento, dashboard

I am facing the issue in `Unable to read response, or response is empty; This error occurred in the Zend_Http_Client->request('GET') DashboardController.php. I don't how to solve this.

In the report error message are shown.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:45:"Unable to read response, or response is empty";i:1;s:1096:"#0 .../lib/Varien/Http/Client.php(61): Zend_Http_Client->request('GET')
#1 .../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(100): Varien_Http_Client->request('GET')
#2 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->tunnelAction()
#3 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('tunnel')
#4 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 .../app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 .../index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:552:".../dashboard/tunnel/key/e49658d07a3b41c7fd32be96b5ae0acf/?ga=eyJjaHQiOiJsYyIsImNoZiI6ImJnLHMsZjRmNGY0fGMsbGcsOTAsZmZmZmZmLDAuMSxlZGVkZWQsMCIsImNobSI6IkIsZjRkNGIyLDAsMCwwIiwiY2hjbyI6ImRiNDgxNCIsImNoZCI6ImU6ampPTzQ0T09BQVZWSEhWVk9PSEhBQWNjQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBIiwiY2h4dCI6IngseSIsImNoeGwiOiIwOnx8fDE0OjAwfHx8MTc6MDB8fHwyMDowMHx8fDIzOjAwfHx8MDI6MDB8fHwwNTowMHx8fDA4OjAwfHx8MTE6MDB8MTp8MHwxfDJ8M3w0fDV8Nnw3fDh8OSIsImNocyI6IjU";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I don't know why this error occurred and also gradle build failed How to solve this error .

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in DashboardController.php are using Zend_Http_Client to send a request to somewhere, maybe it's API call and that API is not responding.

You need to find this call in code and wrap it into the try catch statements and handle the error.

```
        try { 
            // do request... 
        } catch (Zend_Http_Client_Exception $e) { 
            $success = false; //handle error here
        }
```

For more specific answer you need attach DashboardController code

Comment: i did this test, I discovered that the problem was in the server firewall. thank you for help